# Ingress rule in which the parameter to be sent carries a / and the ingress takes it as a rule

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Good morning, I am currently working on the deployment of a service in kubernetes ingress and I am having a problem, I need to send an encrypted parameter through sso as input parameter in the url through the get method, and it is giving me the problem that the ingress is taking it as a rule:

My Ingress Rules

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-develop
  namespace: develop
  annotations: 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "20"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-dev
  tls: 
    - secretName: srvdevma1-ssl
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /userProfile/v3.6/users/.*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: 
            name: user-profile
            port: 
              number: 8080
```

As input parameter I must send an encrypted parameter in sso like the following:

2IuUHKRcst/S6GGf+RKONg==

The problem is that when I send it, it is taking the / as a rule so it returns a resource not found error:

[image]

Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to url encode your value as it is part of the URL. And it has charactes which have special meaning, characters like "/", "+", "=" in your value.